# New to PowerShell Put

Tags: powershell, api, rest, put

I want to change the name of the website from the following scenario and am having no luck.

So I have success accessing this REST API with the following script:

> $apiKey = "my api key"
> $resource = "https://{host}/api/v3/vendor/1035/"
> $contentType = "application/json"
> $headers = @{
> "ABC-ApiKey" = $apiKey
> }
> Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType $contentType -Uri $resource -Headers $headers

I get the following output:

[image]
I then tried this for a PUT command:

> $apiKey = "my api key"
> $resource = "https://{host}/api/v3/vendor/1035/"
> $contentType = "application/json"
> $headers = @{
> "ABC-ApiKey" = $apiKey
> }
> $data = @{
> website = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
> }
> $json = $data | ConvertTo-Json
> Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -ContentType $contentType -Uri $resource -Headers $headers -Body $json

And I get this error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out.  I have to include ALL the fields in the JSON file even if I am only updating one.

So now my $data looks like this:

> $data = @{
> vendorId          = 1035
> vendorCode        = ‘WPP’
> vendorInfo        = ‘West Penn Power’
> address           = @{addressTypeId=2; line1=’PO Box 3687’; line2=’’; line3=’’; city='Akron';
> state=’OH’; country=’US’; postalCode=’44309-3687’; latitude=’’; longitude=’’}
> ediCode           = ‘’
> payDays           = 14
> createdBy         = @{userId=’1046’; userCode=’amr’; fullName=’Alexandra Reagan’}
> createdDate       = '2021-05-14T15=36=14.513'
> modifiedBy        = @{userId=’1046’; userCode=’amr’; fullName=’Alexandra Reagan’}
> modifiedDate      = ‘2021-05-14T15=36=14.513’
> website           = ‘https=//stackoverflow.com’
> rates             = {@{rateId=1080; name=’General Power Service WP-GP30F’; commodity=’’}}
> vendorDescription = ‘’
> }